# Fragment gives me an error while inflating 1

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm at the learning stage of fragment so if my question sounds stupid then please let it go and give your advices.

So i have developed one very simple application from Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvG20PAUdcU) and got some error that i have posted below with my other class files.

Interface

```
package com.example.fragmentdemo;

public interface Communicator {
public void respond(String data);
}
```

Activity

```
package com.example.fragmentdemo;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2=(FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_b);
        f2.changeText(data);
    }
}
```

FragmentA

```
package com.example.fragmentdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentA extends Fragment{
    Button btn;
    int counter=0;
    Communicator comm;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {
            counter=0;
        }
        else
        {
            counter=savedInstanceState.getInt("counter");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_a,container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btn=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);

        comm=(Communicator)getActivity();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                comm.respond(counter+""+" times");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("counter",counter);
    }

}
```

FragmentB

```
package com.example.fragmentdemo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    TextView txt;
String data;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            data=savedInstanceState.getString("data");
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_b, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
    public void changeText(String dta)
    {
        txt.setText(dta);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("data", data);
    }
}
```

activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/my_lay">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo.FragmentB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdemo.FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me" />

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_b

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00FF00" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Log error

```
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Process: com.example.fragmentdemo, PID: 1784
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragmentdemo/com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     ... 11 more
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090051 type #0x12 is not valid
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2314)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.example.fragmentdemo.FragmentB.onCreateView(FragmentB.java:25)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:80)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at com.example.fragmentdemo.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:1)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
07-22 02:43:13.076: E/AndroidRuntime(1784):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: show your xml here

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090051 type #0x12 is not valid`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initialize this in fragment class in each**

```
View rootView;
```

**On create**

```
  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);


  btn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

 // do for all like that
  return rootView;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In both fragments, you are inflating an 'id':

```
return inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_a,container, false);
return inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_b,container, false);
```

but you need tu inflate the layout:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container, false);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout is not an ID, use the following in your onCreateView() of both your fragments. You need to inflate the layout

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a,container, false);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b,container, false);
```